# iOS Swift Json Serialization breaking on strings with a return

Tags: ios, json, swift

If I return "test"  with/without spaces it works.  But when I return a value that a user stored using a return in the string then it fails with a nil error but when I look in the NSLog the value is there....

Code Before Failure

```
var url:NSURL = NSURL(string:PassURL)!
    var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

    var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

    var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = postData
    request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


    var reponseError: NSError?
    var response: NSURLResponse?

    var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)

    if ( urlData != nil ) {
        let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

        NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

        if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
        {
            var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

            var error: NSError?

//FAILS HERE
let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as! NSDictionary
```

NSLog

```
2015-07-29 08:52:26.622 testApp[20648:187508] Response ==> {"success":1, "test": "Going to Return Now
Second Line"}
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

But the value is not nil...

NSError

```
Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unescaped control character around character 41.) UserInfo=0x7f9c9942b050 {NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character 41.})
```

The unescaped character is the return, how can I allow json to accept this?

Comment: Please add some more core

Comment: @AshishKakkad just added more code before the failure

Comment: The reason why that would happen is because your string is returning nil via the parser. Could you post the `urlData` variable as a String?

Comment: @theMonster I couldnt po the urlstring but I got the NSError ---------> Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unescaped control character around character 24.) UserInfo=0x7f9c9942b050 {NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character 41.})

Comment: Try let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:nil , error: &error) as! NSDictionary

Comment: @AnkitaShah no luck with the code above =(

Comment: Try to use dataTaskWithRequest() of NSURLSession class. It worked for me for parsing JSON data. Also I passed NSData to the resultant method, rather than passing the String. In resultant method convert data to JSON string. Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't post the actual string from the URLRequest, I can't say **exactly** what's wrong with it. But it sounds like characters no. 24 and 41 are not JSON compliant.

I'd review: [json.org](http://json.org). And paste it into: [jsonlint.com](http://pro.jsonlint.com) which'll give you more specifics. And find out why your endpoint is returning invalid JSON.

If you'd like to handle NSJSONSerialization returning nil, simply wrap it in an if let:

```
if let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as? NSDictionary {
    /* It's a valid JSON object */
} else {
    /* It's not a valid JSON object */
}
```

**Note:** Having an array at the root of the json, is not handled by this. If you want to handle that, just expand an else if let as? NSArray. Also, if urlData is nil, this will crash since we're force unwrapping it still.

Comment: The character is a return.  I need to find a way to handle it, any suggestions?

Comment: Is their a way in JSON serialization to parse returns in a string? or is my request impossible through JSON?

Comment: if my string contains a return, allow it and dont mark it as an unescaped string

Comment: I don't think you can do it from `NSJSONSerialization`. However, you could just use string functions to find/replace the text.

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
```

**OR**

```
var error:NSError? = nil

var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:nil, error: &error) as? NSDictionary
```

Comment: the second part of your answer works but then breaks this ---> let success:NSInteger = jsonData!.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger

Comment: saying success is nil but the value is there